# Extracting year using strftime in sqldf

Tags: r, strftime, sqldf

I am trying to extract the year from a date field using SQLDF function.  I was hoping that SQL's DATEPART would work but allas I am needing to use STRFTIME instead (I think).  When I apply the code, I am getting NA under the YYYY.  My code is below:

```
dw_Calendar = read.csv("C:\dw_Calendar.csv")
# ensure that the date field is in a date format
dw_Calendar$newDate <- as.Date(dw_Calendar$FullDate)

CalendarSum <- sqldf("
select newDate,
strftime('%U', newDate) as YYYY
from dw_Calendar
")
```

Comment: That works 100%, thanks

Answer (score 6):

The default sqlite backend that sqldf uses is not ideal for dealing with dates as it has no date or datetime types but it does have functions that deal with them so you can do this.  (Note that the R Date type is stored in the sqlite database as days since the Epoch and by multiplying by 3600 * 24 we get the seconds since the Epoch which puts it in the timestamp representation that sqlite's strftime expects.)

```
library(sqldf)
mydates <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2000-01-01")) # test input

sqldf("select strftime('%Y', date * 3600 * 24, 'unixepoch') year from mydates")
##   year
## 1 2000
```

It's a bit easier if you use the H2 backend since it has a real date type and associated functions:

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)

sqldf("select year(date) year from mydates")
##   year
## 1 2000
```

**Note:** Next time please provide self contained code and all inputs in the question so that anyone else can run your code.